# Angular/Flask http post doesn't work, data hasn't been sent

Tags: angular, flask, post, header

It seems like http post doesn't send the data to server. I think I forgot something, but can't see what.

Here my service

```
passChosenSymtom(symptoms:any){
    console.log(symptoms)
    const lol={symptoms: symptoms}//consider lol={'x':[0,1]}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(lol))
    return this.http.post(this.resultatSymptoms2,JSON.stringify(lol))
  }
```

Component

```
getResult(){
    this.symps.passChosenSymtom(this.allDisease).subscribe({
      next: (obj) => this.assignmentForResult(obj),
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      complete: () => console.info('complete')
      }
    )
  }
```

Server

```
@app.route('/zaebal',methods =['POST'])
def dont_even_work():
    print(request)
    print(request.form)#I recieve this dict ImmutableMultiDict([])
    print(request.args)
   #I have to resend response to dont get a internal error which says server didnt return anything
    
    response =jsonify({
        'predicted_disease': 'fake'
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response
```

Comment: Any errors in your network tab?

Comment: @MikeOne.No there are no errors.
Only if I don't send the response to the client I will get internal error 500.The problem is that I receive ImmutableDict with no elements after post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem.
I write my solution here,if someone get the same problem.
So ,Http request from the client (Angular) sends the Json format data.But the server (Flask) receives data with another format (specific format for Flask) ,so after receiving the request you should use `request.get_json()` to get the json from request.And dont use Json.stringify in client kind useless.